# Installing Prolog Mode to Aquamacs on OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, installation, swi-prolog, osx-yosemite, aquamacs

Let me start by saying i'm new to Mac OS and this may be a simple question but trying to find the answer is really confusing me.
I have recently installed SWI-Prolog and Aquamacs to start learning how to create small prolog programs. I want to install this Prolog mode to Aquatics (http://bruda.ca/emacs/prolog_mode_for_emacs) however I am not sure how these instructions convert to Mac.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and please avoid making explanations too difficult!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK's the instructions, for an Emacs>=24.1:

- Read these instructions carefully to the end.
- Get some ice-cream, to relax you, so you can better focus.
- Do nothing.
- Enjoy the result of your hard work.

[ Background: extracts from Emacs's ChangeLog file:

```
2011-01-11  Stefan Bruda  <stefan@bruda.ca> 

 * progmodes/prolog.el: Replace by a whole new file.
```

]